# Computing inverse of a matrix with an example

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

A) You go to the shops on Monday and buy 1 apple, 1 banana, and 1 carrot; the whole transaction totals €15. On Tuesday you buy 3 apples, 2 bananas, 1 carrot, all for €28. Then on Wednesday 2 apples, 1 banana, 2 carrots, for €23.

A$
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ = $
\begin{bmatrix}
s_m \\
s_t \\
s_w \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
Where a, b, c, are the prices of apples, bananas, and carrots. And each s is the total for that day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday).

B) If every week, you go to the shops and buy the same amount of apples, bananas, and oranges on Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday; and every week you get a new list of daily totals - then you should solve the system in general.

That is, find the inverse of the matrix you used in A.(Source: Mathematics for Machine Learning: Linear Algebra course by Imperial College London on Coursera).

Though I could manage to solve the equation:a = 3, b = 7, c = 5 by back substitution, here is my attempt to find inverse, which is perhaps faulty somewhere.

a + b + c = 15;
3a + 2b + c = 28;
2a + b + 2c = 23.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ $
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ =$
\begin{bmatrix}
15 \\
17 \\
-30 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$AA^{-1}$ = $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$  $
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$6a_{33}$ = 1 or $a_{33}$ = 1/6

0$(a_{12})$ + (-1)$(a_{22})$ + (-2)$(a_{32})$ = 1

-$(a_{22})$ - $(a_{32})$ = 1

As told in the answer to this thread, I am now proceeding with original A (still not clear why the echelon form of A above did not work).

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ $
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ $
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & -1 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ $
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ $
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$6a_{33}$ = 3

$a_{33}$ = 3/6 = 0.5 (this apparently is correct)

But unable to find the values of other elements in $
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$ So seeking help how to proceed to find values of remaining elements in a systematic manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They need you to express $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ as $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}= B \begin{bmatrix}s_m\\s_t\\s_w\end{bmatrix}$ where the inverse of $A$ is a matrix $B$ s.t. $BA = I = AB$.

Here, $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 && 1 && 1\\3 && 2 && 1\\2 && 1 && 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = A^{-1} = \frac{\text{adj}(A)}{\text{det}(A)} = \begin{bmatrix}-1.5 && 0.5 && 0.5\\2 && 0 && -1\\0.5 && -0.5 && 0.5\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: You need  one step more in order that the OP understands, i.e.,  express how $A^{-1}$ is used... to recover the unit prices.

Comment: It means first I should know how to compute adj(A) and det(A)! Though I should search this by myself, but any reference to link will help.

Comment: @TechcosecLimited Take a look at these : (1) [Adjoint of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix); (2) [Determinant of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the suggestion, but I left out that last step for the OP to figure out. Basically, with the inverse, OP can verify that the answer initially obtained also makes sense.

Comment: Updated this thread by adding my attempt to find inverse.

Comment: @JeanMarie Updated this thread by adding my attempt to find inverse that needs help.

Comment: @TechcosecLimited Did you try using elementary row operations to get the second and third-row of the first matrix in that form(Echelon form) in the equation right below $AA^{-1} = I$? Your approach is correct, but try doing it with the original A, and you'll be able to find the inverse.

Comment: @psitama I have updated this thread while trying to find inverse with original A.